# WebSocket handshake not working for deployed rails 4.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

I am working on a [Go Game in rails](https://github.com/tlehman/goga.me), and to enable live gameplay I am using websockets. The [websocket-rails](https://github.com/websocket-rails/) gem works pretty nicely for this, and I have everything working locally.

After I deploy to http://goga.me, the WebSocket handshake fails with `Websocket connection to 'ws://goga.me/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the handshake is failing is that nginx is not acknowledging the WebSocket upgrade:

Adding this to the nginx config solved the problem:

```
location /websocket {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

The option `proxy_http_version 1.1` means use HTTP 1.1, which is required for WebSockets.

Then the following two lines tell nginx to acknowledge the upgrade and complete the handshake. This was noted in [High Performance Browser Networking](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch17.html#_deploying_websocket_infrastructure)